# TCL catch ignores error

Tags: tcl, catch-block

```
proc handler { args } { 
    if { [catch {eval $args} errorMessage] } {
        _report_error "$errorMessage"
    }
}
```

args is script which has call from another TCL file

```
proc is_threshold_percent {thresholdValue } {
   #some code here
    if { [ string is double -strict $threshold ] && $threshold < 0 } {
        error "Threshold ${threshold}% must be positive."
    }
    return 1
}
return 0
}
```

Without catch  block it;s normally printed error and program exits with an error, but I need handle the error message and add more details and catch block ignores the error and finishes 'normally' .

Comment: Catch is very thoroughly tested. It does exactly what it says it does. I would suspect that the you have given instructions to Tcl that are not exactly what you _think_ they are; Tcl never tries to second-guess what you mean.

Comment: Maybe create a minimal example that shows what you think goes wrong?